# airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Can't decrypt encrypted password for login=login, FERNET_KEY configuration is missing

Tags: python, encryption, airflow

Using **PythonVirtualenvOperator** I'm getting this error: airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Can't decrypt encrypted password for login=login, FERNET_KEY configuration is missing

I think Virtual env is not understanding this configuration. My config.cfg it's ok and I never had this issue, but as I'm using VirtualEnv probably not understanding this config (Im not sure about)

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

This error doesn't have anything to do with your installed package.
This error simply happens when somewhere in your persist storage, such as a database, you have secret information such as a password or something that is encrypted and when airflow, or better to say python tries to decrypt it it faces some malfunction.

those malfunctions usually occurs by the user, **for example in my case as I'm facing this error**, I tried to copy the connections and variables from another airflow db into my development airflow db, now airflow telling me that due to mismatch between these 2 environments, hash keys cant be understood so I simply have to redo what I've done and start creating those one by one.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try creating your .env file where you can put the foreign key and the different settings you need to launch the airflow, like passwords and environment variables.